# Should I omit the article? Also, is the preposition "of" redundant?

Tags: definite-articles, redundancy, concision

In the sentence below, should I omit the article because "efficiencies" is plural and uncountable? Is the second "of" redundant? How can I make this sentence more concise?

*The factors that influence the containment and mitigation efficiencies, the spreading rate, and the total contamination of the waste and of the surrounding environment were also investigated.*

Comment: Which article are you considering omitting? Which instance of *of*?

Comment: The first _the_ and the second _of_.